# QueryValue with dynamic value which depends on column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

```
@foreach(var a in db.Query(selectQueryforSubj, currID))
            {   
                <tr>
                    <td>@a.SubjectCode</td> 
                    <td>@a.DescriptiveTitle</td>
                    <td>@a.Units</td>
                    <td>@a.Prereq</td>

            @foreach(var b in db.QueryValue("SELECT " +username+ " FROM Subjects WHERE SubjectId=@0", a.SubjectId))
                    {
                    <td>@b</td>
                    }
                </tr> 
           }
```

I have columns named after different usernames and I want to load its values (which is their grades) depending on the SubjectId of my Query "a" and the column named after the username of whom I am viewing.

However, this error occurs.

*Cannot implicitly convert type '`int`' to '`System.Collections.IEnumerable`'*

and my line which have a "`QueryValue`" is highlighted in red.

I know I shouldn't use a "`foreach`" for my `QueryValue`. But I really don't know what I'll use instead. :(

Comment: One thing that's wrong with your code is that you appear to be writing  a razor view with database queries inside it! ;-)

Comment: Another thing is that your query is opened for sql injection attack

Comment: It seems your QueryValue returns an integer. Do you have source code for QueryValue method?

Comment: I need to confirm something, guys. Can I really use +username+ inside a SELECT statement to denote the column_name which is equivalent to the username of the one I'm viewing? I tried to use the usual SELECT statement and it worked. but I need the column_name to be dependent on the username of whom I am viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Query instead of QueryValue in the second foreach loop. QueryValue will return a single value while Query will return an IEnumerable of mupltiple values so you can enumerate them as you do in the outermost foreach loop. If there you want to get a single value do not use the foreach loop at all.

Sample 1:

```
@foreach(var a in db.Query(selectQueryforSubj, currID))
            {   
                <tr>
                    <td>@a.SubjectCode</td> 
                    <td>@a.DescriptiveTitle</td>
                    <td>@a.Units</td>
                    <td>@a.Prereq</td>

            @foreach(var b in db.Query("SELECT " +username+ " FROM Subjects WHERE SubjectId=@0", a.SubjectId))
                    {
                    <td>@b</td>
                    }
                </tr> 
           }
```

Sample 2

```
@foreach(var a in db.Query(selectQueryforSubj, currID))
            {   
                <tr>
                    <td>@a.SubjectCode</td> 
                    <td>@a.DescriptiveTitle</td>
                    <td>@a.Units</td>
                    <td>@a.Prereq</td>

                    <td>db.QueryValue("SELECT " +username+ " FROM Subjects WHERE SubjectId=@0", a.SubjectId)</td>

                </tr> 
           }
```

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions and experimented something. I have a column under 'Subjects' table with a name 'test2', which is an account I previously created. I used ("SELECT test2 FROM Subjects WHERE SubjectId=@0", a.SubjectId) instead of the one with a +username+. And it worked. It showed the data I was looking for. But I need the column_name ('test2') to be dependent on whose account I am viewing (which can be retrieved from a different table).